# window:beforeunload on IE 11 - always pop up the unsave dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

When adding a listener to the global window object for the beforeunload event, IE 11 does not behave as Chrome and Firefox.

This is used with the Angular "ngForm", when form is dirty and not submitted, then the user try to click to another component(routing), it will pop up the warning dialog. If the user not modify the form, it would not pop up the browser-native dialog prompt.

However, in IE, even the user didn't modify the form, then try to navigate to other component, it still pop up the warning dialog.

I'm not sure is because the  window: beforeunload in IE will unload the page every time you navigate to other component?

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  canDeactivate(): boolean {
    return !this.form.dirty || this.form.submitted;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An almost cross-browser working example would be close to the following:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/"; // is equivalent to event.preventDefault();

  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
  return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
});
```

so before returning make sure you update the `event.returnValue`  as well.